# Not Run App With Admob (help) Error (Import

Tags: android, admob

please send tested admob working with api 18(android4.2) or higher

MainActivity.java

> Error at import files not exist related admob import
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest; import
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

```
package com.a.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .build();
        AdView adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.a.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.a.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

layout  main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adSize="BANNER"
                           ads:adUnitId="MY ID"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you include admob jar

Comment: how can get admobsdk

Answer (score 1):

Hope you've already references the google play services library within your project. If you haven't, make sure your remove any admob sdk jar in your `/libs`/ folder and reference the google play services library version 4 or later in your project. Then

In your layout, change :

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

to:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

In your manifest, add:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Make sure you add within the `<application` tag